# Setup Static IP on headless Raspberry PI 4 with Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTS using configuration files on boot partition only

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, static-ip

***Problem:***

I'm installing Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi for my robots, headless setup, only power and ethernet/wifi.

I'm cycling through images quickly, it's tedious to always be using a DHCP, make first access and change IP from inside the operating system via SSH, then reconnect with the right static IP.

***What I tried:***

I'm developing on windows, the ethernet configuration files are in a linux partitions that is not seen by windows out of the box.

The boot partition is convenient, and already has several settings I edit before plugging in the card (like GPIOs). I want to be able to setup a static IP by changing a config file on the BOOT partition.

I researched the topic, and no solution worked. e.g. the line on config.txt does nothing
`ip=192.168.0.5::192.168.0.1:255.255.255.0:rpi:eth0:off`

***Question:***

Is there a way to setup a static IP on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTS on config.txt or another file inside boot?

Can I place a script in BOOT that is executed the first time the Raspberry Pi is booted?

***Answer:***
cmdline.txt
`ip=192.168.0.5::192.168.0.1:255.255.255.0:rpi:eth0:off` 
As far as I can tell, it works by injecting through the tty serial interface the IP command that is processed and setup the ETH0 interface.

Comment: I fail to understand why you think you need to know the IP to ssh.

Comment: My laptop is 192.168.0.199 with 255.255.255.0. It will not connect to a virgin image using raspberrypi.local as address

Comment: I haven't used current Ubuntu (because it requires a ludicrous amount of memory) but it is extremely unlikely the hostname is raspberrypi!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `ip` has to be inserted in the `cmdline.txt` file to set a static IP address at first startup.

ip=[IP-Address]::[Gateway IP]:[Subnetmask]:[Hostname]:[interface name]:[Autoconfig on/off]

```
[Example of /boot/cmdline.txt]
[some other stuff...]ip=192.168.0.2::192.168.0.1:255.255.255.0:rpi:eth0:off
```